# Position Fixed Broken in Chrome with Flash behind

Tags: flash, google-chrome, position, overlay, css-position

I have a strange bug that recently started happening in Chrome (works fine in IE, FF and even Safari). This was working a few weeks ago, so I am assuming this is a bug that came about in a recent Chrome build.

Basically I have flash fixed "behind" the page, and I have an overlay fixed above the page (controls for video).

I know Chrome 22 included separate stacking contexts for fixed elements, but this was working a few weeks ago and we are on Chrome 27 now, so that does not seem to be relevant. I have a zindex on both elements too.

Any ideas?

*Edit*: I forgot to mention the overlay **is** in the correct place, and it is clickable, it is just not visible in the correct place when you scroll.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is a bug/regression in Chrome and have submitted a bug report ([249235](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249235)).

A workaround is to force the layer to be rendered on the GPU with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` (targeted only to Chrome).