# Fixed position element is flashing in Chrome when scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, positioning

I am trying to make this website. It works great on Firefox, but not in Chrome. I fixed the header to the top. When scrolling it sticks on top and it is flashing in Chrome.

I don't know why, but I tried to fix this but could not. How can I fix the problem?

Site link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88666744/HTML/works/qcolor2Copy-fl/index.html

Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: its still in my chrome. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position Fixed Broken in Chrome with Flash behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079857/position-fixed-broken-in-chrome-with-flash-behind)

Comment: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to `.header_area`

Comment: @rd5 Add this as answer please. It's easier to read the answer and not looking the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to rd5. He helps me out.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```